# how to add y axis label(custom text) in rickshaw graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

I want to display custom text as y axis label.
I have attached the sample screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var yAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y({
    graph: graph,
    tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT
});

yAxis.render();
```